# Webkit or W3C Notifications in Chrome for Android?

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, notifications

I'am trying to use html5 notifications for a web app.
It's working in Chrome 26 (on OSX) with both webkitNotifications and Notification (W3C).

I've read that webkitNotifications is also supported in Chrome for Android [here](http://www.a-community.at/pCMS-CodeSnippets/Archiv.2012/Beitrag.2012.12.28.001/) and [here](http://caniuse.com/notifications) but I can't make it works.
I've simply try to debug both Notification and window.webkitNotifications objects to see if it's implemented. Chrome don't find this two objects.

I need some help : is caniuse.com wrong or is it me ?

Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick Answer:  It is not supported yet on Chrome for Android and it hasn't been in the past either.

Just for clarity for other readers the current revision of Chrome is 27, and it is not supported in the this version or versions prior.